# Корреляция в Seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, seaborn

Имеется [фрейм 1460*81](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data)

Используя:

```
sns.heatmap(hou.corr(), cmap= sns.color_palette(palette="RdBu"),linewidths=0.5,annot=True)  :
```

1. Каким образом сделать картинку побольше?

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   2. Объясните, как по цветам различать корреляцию? Т.е., что значат синие/красные отношения колонок?
      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для начала уберите подписи `annot=False`, чтобы на графике был виден цвет соответствующий корреляции.
2. Чтобы задать размер графика:

   ```
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
   sns.heatmap(..., ax=ax)
   ```
3. >

> Объясните как по цветам различать корреляцию? Т.е что значат
>   синие/красные отношения колонок?

Справа от графика находится шкала показывающая соотношение цвета и корреляции. Синий - большая корреляция, красный - маленькая.

4. для визуализации корреляции лучше использовать модуль (абсолютное значение) корреляции, т.к. нас интересуют признаки с высокой по модулю корреляцией вне зависимости от её знака.

Comment: C цветом все понятно. Я спрашиваю про физический смысл корреляции. Т.е. одинаковые(или взаимосвязанные) значения по колонкам? Тогда что есть отрицательная корреляция?

Comment: @Eugene_Venev, https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @Eugene_Venev, отрицательная корреляция показывает обратную связь - когда значения одной переменной убывают, значения другой возрастают